# How to retrieve actual window dimensions of a pop-up in IE8 ONLY? (NOT VIEWPORT)

Tags: internet-explorer-8, popup, dimensions

I have a script that positions the popup at the bottom right corner of the users screen every time.  However, IE8 could care less about the fact that there is more to the window than the viewport.  How do I get the size of that in IE8?

```
var popUpWidth = window.outerWidth; // does not work in IE8!
var popUpHeight = window.outerHeight; // does not work in IE8!
```

Comment: Are you using some kind of Javascript library, or is it just vanilla JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE8 doesn't have the outerWidth / outerHeight property, try instead:

```
   document.documentElement.clientHeight;
   document.documentElement.clientWidth;
```

Here's an example http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/get-document-height-cross-browser/

Comment: For others, this will return the width/height reduced by the scrollbars size so `window.outerWidth != document.documentElement.clientWidth`

Answer (score 0):

Set the window to a given size. Obtain the size of the client window. This will be smaller by the amount of window chrome. Use the difference to calculate the window size for any client size.

The initial size is completely arbitrary but the current client size plus an optional fudge factor will cause the least change on screen.